# add up all value's of a property in an array Vuejs

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

I am working on a small app and I have a array with objects and within the objects 2 property's, one called 'label' and one 'value'. What I would like is to add up all values of the property 'value', So that I have one total value.

Vue/JS

```
data() {

totalRequest: 0,

   donutData: [
        { label: 'Openstaande verzoeken', value: 20 },
        { label: 'Geaccepteerde verzoeken', value: 25 },
        { label: 'Afgewezen verzoeken', value: 10 }
    ],

},

created() {
        this.totalRequest = //here goes the function to add up all value's of the property 'value' (total value should be 55)
}
```

HTML

```
total value {{ totalRequest }}
```

So in this example I have 3 objects with a total value of 55 (all 3 property 'value'). How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

**Answer by dashton, reproduced for vue**

```
created() {
        this.totalRequest = this.donutData.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0);
}
```

Comment: Array.Reduce is all you need. `donutData.Reduce( (acc, item) => { 
return acc += item.value; 
}, 0);`

Comment: I've tried it with Array.Reduce but that didn't worked. Is that possible with objects? I need the second property in the object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This has nothing to do with vue, seems like a javascript question, there's tons of way of doing this, the simpler would be just do a forEach:

es4:

```
for(i in donutData) { this.totalRequest += donutData[i].value; }
```

BUT as you asked how to show {{ totalRequest }} you might want to look at computed properties:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Which is a way vue has to dynamically set data in views, so you could take dashton's answer and do:

HTML

```
total value {{ totalRequest }}
```

Vue/js

```
data() {
   donutData: [
        { label: 'Openstaande verzoeken', value: 20 },
        { label: 'Geaccepteerde verzoeken', value: 25 },
        { label: 'Afgewezen verzoeken', value: 10 }
    ],

},
computed: {
    totalRequest() {
      return this.donutData.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using computed at such places is a better approach. +1.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks

Answer (score 15):

This will work:

```
var sum = donutData.reduce((acc, item) => acc + item.value, 0);
```

Comment: Alright this is awesome. I will reproduce the answer in my question specific for VueJS.

Comment: When we introduce the local variable to get a sum of array value in Vuex computed property, it loses the reactivity. This solution overcomes that issue.

Comment: This isn't summing up the values for me, rather so just adding them together literally.
E.g my vals are 800 and 200, my output is 800200

Answer (score 1):

All the given responses seems okay, if you still face the problem and you have the exact code, just make sure your data(value to sum) is an integer.

For instance, if value = "12" and "34" you will get "1234" as the result instead of 46

Use parseInt() to convert to integer:

```
array.reduce((acc, item) => acc +parseInt( item.value), 0)
```

Comment: My values are still doing a literal add, even using parseInt()

Comment: The reduce function syntax is  ```array.reduce((total, currentValue) =>  total+ current, initialValue)```   .  Failure to provide the initialValue can lead to failure to return the expected response. Do test the array if you will get the right values before reducing

Comment: My fix was to implement the parseInt() around the actual output, not the computation/method

`{{parseInt(function_name)}}`